# pip command is not working after upgrade from 19.2.3 to 20.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

pip command is not working after an upgrade from 19.2.3 to 20.0.
Facing this issue in python.
How to go back to previous version of pip?

C:\Users\sagkumar>pip --version
pip 20.0 from c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

```
C:\Users\sagkumar>pip install psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\sagkumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions import (
  File "c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (c:\users\sagkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Seems you're not alone; perhaps a problem in pip 20: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59842600/7976758

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

> Collecting pip
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/36/67f809c135c17ec9b8276466cc57f35b98c240f55c780689ea29fa32f512/pip-20.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 145kB/s
> Installing collected packages: pip
> Found existing installation: pip 18.1
> Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
> Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
> Successfully installed pip-20.0.1

```
python -m pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script to downgrade to any version:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python - 'pip==19.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to downgrade to an older version, you could use this command line:

```
 curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python - 'pip==19.3.1'
```